# Load JSON data into div based off of select option value

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to load data from a JSON file that is based off of the option that is selected by the user. I have it working but I know it can be written much more efficient and I'm having a hard time finding a good place to start. I'll include an example of my code below, but it's pulling in various counties based off of the state you choose. You'll notice though that I'm checking each value with an else if statement to load in the correct data. I'm sure there has to be a way to load what I need but without 49 other else if statements.

HTML:

```
<select id='test-select'>
    <option>AL</option>
    <option>AK</option>
    <option>AZ</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var cities = [];
    $.getJSON('/assets/shared/misc/counties.json', function(json) {
        // push json to data to cities array
        cities.push(json);

        // map over each item item 
        $('.state-names').map(function(index) {

            // load in json data based off of select option
            $('#test-select').on('change', function() {
                var target = $('#test-select option:selected').val();
                console.log(target);
                if (target == 'AL') {
                    $('.state-names').text(cities[0].AL);
                } else if (target == 'AK') {
                    $('.state-names').text(cities[0].AK);
                } else if (target == 'AZ') {
                    $('.state-names').text(cities[0].AZ);
                } else if (target == 'AR') {
                    $('.state-names').text(cities[0].AR);
                } // end else if block
            }); // end test select function
        }); // end map function

        console.log(cities);

    }); // end getJSON call
```

This is just the condensed version, but it's basically this plus many more options and else if's. Is there a way I can somehow set an index to whatever state is selected to match the key in the JSON file without having to make so many calls? Any help is greatly appreciated. If I left out any important details I can certainly share more information. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the value of `target` as property name:

```
$('.state-names').text(cities[0][target]);
```

See [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: Thank you so much! That went off perfect and was easy to code in there. I knew there had to be something I was missing. Thanks again so much for the help.